# Windows simulate network cable loss

Tags: windows, networking, simulate

I'm trying to program some tool and i want to simulate a network cable lose with it.
So i want to get the same effect like i unplug the networkcable from my computer and plug it in again. It's not the same as the '/renew' / '/release' commands. When i disconnect / connect it manualy it look likes windows remember some things and it's connected very fast back again. 
Is it possible and maybe how to do it in code?

Thank you very much!

---

edit:
I found another program that just blocks all ports, this is ok for me too but how to do in code :).

Comment: One possibility I can think of is a batch file to change your IP routing tables to a non-existent router for a while.

Comment: I don't get the point of *simulating* it.  Just unplug it.

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate a network failure or network unplugged, there's a difference. More to the point why does your app care what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the fetch and send data bitrate to 0

Alternatively you could just set the receive bitrate to 0 bits and leave the send untouched this would also simulator the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a great little tool called [WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) . You can use it to simulate different WAN scenarios. Loss of connectivity is one possibility, but also jitter, noise and more on the line. Even simulating a dial-up connection. Runs as a bootable ISO and very easy to use.